# treeview with radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, radiobuttonlist

I am developing a website.  I need to show a `RadioButtonList` in a `TreeView`, but I can't find any solutions showing me how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a RadioButton before the treenode instead of the checkbox:

```
protected void TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
  e.Node.Text = "<input type='radio' />" + e.Node.Text;
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.Render(writer);
    TreeView1.RenderControl(writer);
}
```

Hope it helps